# Efficient way to render particles to a texture using a compute shader

Tags: optimization, shader, hlsl, particle-system

I'm trying to render a particle sytem onto a texture (2048x2048, 2 channels of 16 bits floating precision) using compute shaders. Each particle is basically an 8x8 texture with a position and a scale that I write to it's corresponding place on the texture. Computations to write the texture should be pretty fast : it's a blending depending on the particle texture value.

The final size of each texture usually remain small (it can reach up to 20x20 pixels on the final texture).

The method I'm using is to draw each particle with a different thread. Therefore I draw n particles per work group.
I've tried different workgroup sizes but it still feels slow. For something like **500** particles it can take **0.1ms** on a **3090Ti** (and when I draw bigger particles this delay increase really fast).

Am I doing something wrong here ?
Also, I might draw bigger particles later so I'm looking for solution that work for small particles but I'm also interested for solutions to draw bigger ones.

Comment: GPUs are not really made to render thing in a very short time but rather render complex scenes in a reasonable time (i.e. not 1000 FPS). 0.1 ms is short and certainly half the time should be spent in overheads like PCI device communication, memory allocations, kernel submission/sync, (data transfer?), etc. If you want to draw a small amount of particles on many textures, then you certainly need to do batch rendering.